# How to write text to a iterm2 session in applescript?

Tags: applescript, iterm2

I am attempting to create a script for iTerm2 that will create a session (by a split) and then enter text into that newly created session. How do I activate the newly created session?

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        split horizontally with default profile
    end tell

    -- Here is what I need help with?
    set _new_session to <what goes here> of current window
    tell _new_session
        write text "ls"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course I figured this out shortly after I posted my question. To get the session you must go through the tabs, which I was not doing. Here is a working example:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        split horizontally with default profile
    end tell

    tell current tab of current window
        set _new_session to last item of sessions
    end tell

    tell _new_session
        select
        write text "ls"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final target is to execute scripts on the shell you could also use

```
set sc to "ping google.com"
do shell script (quoted form of sc)
```

Comment: My final target is to build a script that will open a terminal and create a second session with a terminal editor (micro) open. Then when the script runs again it will check if the editor session exists, if it does it will open the file that I send.

Comment: so you need to open a file in the end? why need a terminal session for that?

Comment: I am writing a script to open a file within an existing terminal editor that is already open in a different pane.

Comment: you want to open it inside the shell with an edior like nano or is it just an open command that will launch third party software?

Comment: In the shell (separate pane), I am messing around with doing this with [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/). Of course, I hope to make it work with any terminal editor (nano, emacs, etc.). It will enable me to maintain a work flow similar to using a single instance editor (e.g., atom)  but completely in a terminal shell. Ideally, it will work when logged into a remote session as well. Just something I am playing with, haven't sunk a bunch of time into it yet but I think it will work. Thanks for the interest.